# LINQ Updating the selected object while doing a left outer join

Tags: c#, linq

In the below code, I have a collection of Employee object. I have to check whether the employee are InOrg or not. For that I do a left join with the InOrgCatalog table and return an anonymous object. I already have an InOrg property 
in my Employee object, so instead of returning an anonymous object I want to return the Employee object with the InOrg property updated. What change I have to do in the query to achieve that?

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>
                {
                    new Employee {  EmployeeId = 1, EmployeeName = "Aaron" , Alias = "AWERAS", InOrg = false},
                    new Employee {  EmployeeId = 2, EmployeeName = "asdfsdf" , Alias = "HJKHJK", InOrg = false},
                    new Employee {  EmployeeId = 3, EmployeeName = "qwerwe" , Alias = "NMUIYUI", InOrg = false},
                    new Employee {  EmployeeId = 4, EmployeeName = "zcvcx" , Alias = "PIOUKJ", InOrg = false},
                };

using (var context = new MyDbContext())
       {
            var result = (from employee in employees
                          join catalog in context.InOrgCatalogs on new { Alias = employee.Alias,  Active = true } equals 
                          new { Alias = catalog.Alias,  Active = catalog.Active }
                          into ps
                          from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select  new { Employee = employee , InOrg = !(p == null)}).ToList();                
       }
```

Comment: Linq is for _querying_, not _updating_.  You can either get the items as-is and loop through, updating the `Employee` object, or you can project to a _new_ `Employee` object, copying al of the property values.

Comment: I'm trying to query the db for a value and not trying to update something in the db. Any solution without recreating a new Employee object will be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me you need to select a new Employeee object rather than an anonymous object.  Then you can update the properties as needed:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var result = (from Employee employee in employees
                  join catalog in context.InOrgCatalogs on new { Alias = employee.Alias, Active = true } equals
                  new { Alias = catalog.Alias, Active = catalog.Active }
                  into ps
                  from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new Employee { EmployeeId = employee.EmployeeId,EmployeeName = employee.EmployeeName, Alias = employee.Alias, InOrg = !(p == null) }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It will be painful if we have multiple properties in the object. In future, if we add a new property we have to make sure this part of code is modified to reflect the change. Any better options?

Comment: You could create a constructor that accepts an existing instance of Employee and a string, value pair to indicate which property you want to change.  A simple switch-case block will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use trick with `let` keyword and double assigning:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var result = (from employee in employees
                  join catalog in context.InOrgCatalogs 
                  on new { Alias = employee.Alias,  Active = true } equals 
                  new { Alias = catalog.Alias,  Active = catalog.Active } into ps
                  from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  let temp = employee.InOrg = (p != null)//it will do the work
                  select employee).ToList();                
}
```

Comment: this gives me Compiler Error CS0832: An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator (EF5)